# URIs for composite objects in RESTful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, uri

I have created the paths:

```
POST /books/4/chapters
```

The `Chapter` entity is part of the `Book` composition. It can not exist in the system without a book. Now after creating a chapter by posting to the URI above, should I create another set of URIs for the answer resource for updating and getting a particular chapter?

`GET /books/4/chapters/6` or `GET /chapters/6`?

> Remember that once you have the primary key for one level, you usually don't need to include the levels above because you've already got your specific object. In other words, you shouldn't need too many cases where a URL is deeper than what we have above /resource/identifier/resource.

*From apigee Web API Design*

This `GET /chapters/6` would be more true to what the article says, however that also means that you object is not in scope of its parent anymore (since it is part of a composite object of class Book). However I feel that this is better since chapters could be a composition of other objects again meaning that you get long nested URIs

`GET /books/4/chapters/5/paragrahps/5` if everything should be in scope of the parent.

What would be the preferred way of doing this

**Edit**

After more thinking it probably will be the best to have URIs like `/books/4/chapters/9` etc since you don't have repositories etc in the code for retrieving a particular feedback without its parent because it is a composite?

Comment: +1 because it is a legit question. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is definitely the way you mentioned. For example :

```
/books/4/chapters -- GET : Retrieve full list of chapters of the book
/books/4/chapters/9 -- GET : Retrieve the 9th chapter of book 4.
```

The important keyword is the *of*. It's a chapter OF a book and it's totally irrelevant to present it without its book. Just doing `/chapters/9` is very unclear. You see it as a full entity, while it really is a subset of a book.

Using the way illustrated over you will have very clear URIs. You a retrieving a specific resource (chapter 9) which is a sub-resource of the other (and thus, you have to be mentioning the "super" resource).

I'd really advise you to take a look at *[this great presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=NEWTPFzt2-E)* by David Zülke, a member of the Symfony team. It's a language-agnostic presentation about REST. More precisely it talks about URIs from 16min~ to 30min~, but the whole presentation is great and worth watching.

---

#### A note about the *apigee* presentation

I've watched it today, and while I do agree with them, in most cases. There is one thing that I see here. While it might be great to be able to retrieve a chapter by

```
/chapter/{its id} -- GET
```

The problem is that, in some cases, you want the ***9th* chapter of a book**, and not necessarily retrieve **chapter *238723*** (which is unclear that it is the 9th chapter). And in that case, it makes more sense to retrieve it by doing :

```
/books/4/chapters/9 -- GET
```

Comment: But you still mean that there should be possible to retrieve a chapter by id like that when it is part of a composition right? Since you normally don't create repositories/dao etc for objects like that, they are part of the book so they are always operated on through the book? It makes the most sense to me atleast.

Comment: And with the last approach, what would happen if you did `/books/4/chapters/9 -- DELETE`, and you had 20 chapters in total. Each chapter have their own persistent ID, but let say you that the chapter order is a transient attribute that is set while adding the chapter to the book. Is that bad? I mean, how would you implement those pretty ids of a chapter (or any other entity) that is part of a composition?

Comment: Well I depends how you make the PKeys of the chapters. Do they have their own id? Do they have a composite key which is the book_id AND an ID (which would be the chapt number). Is it both like they do have an Id, but they also have a unique book_id + order (which would be our 9). I think all these case can be used as long as it is clear in the specification of the api. The most important thing is that there is no ambiguity for users of the API (and they mention that in the apiegee vids) because after all, what you want is that your api gets used.